# Простой переводчик на PHP

Tags: php

Я пытаюсь построить простенький переводчик, логика которого основана на замене введенных значений на значения из базы данных.

```
// подключаем данные из базы
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `dictionary`";
 $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sqls);
 
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
 $word = $r['word'];
 $meaning = $r['meaning'];

//перевод 
$translation[$word] = $meaning;
}

// обработка формы
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
$search = strtolower($_POST['text']);
$translate = $translation[$search];
    
print_r($translate);
 }
```

Код работает если ввести одно слово. Но идея состоит в том, что если введено в форму предложение, каждое отдельное слово из переменной $search должно быть заменено значением $meaning, если оно доступно... чтобы также была возможность пунктуации, а то я так понимаю код сравнивает дословно значения из поля с базой...

Я пробовал реализовать это посредством массива:

```
// в части запроса sql
$translation = array($word => $meaning);

// в части обработки формы
$translate = strtr($search, $translation);
```

Но этот код, увы не работает. Похоже, что введенное значение в переменной $search не соответствует массиву $word и не возвращает никакого результата.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Разбейте переводимую строку заранее на отдельные слова и запрашивайте в БД слова списком (оператор IN) что бы не тянуть весь словарь